# What do the summary index 'psrsvd' fields stand for?

Tags: splunk

Summary indexing in Splunk produces a lot of psrsvd_* fields.  What do they stand for?  I presume they're acronyms or abbreviations.  Here are some examples when averaging the number of bytes returned per client IP, as logged by apache (ie `sistats avg(bytes) by clientip`):

- psrsvd_ct_bytes
- psrsvd_gc
- psrsvd_nc_bytes
- psrsvd_sm_bytes
- psrsvd_ss_bytes
- psrsvd_v
- psrsvd_vt_bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These fields are an artifact of using the si* version of reporting commands.  The fields are specially named so that on retrieval from the summary index, the reporting command (chart/timechart/stats) can properly decode the information.

psrsvd stands for "prestats reserved"

The general pattern is psrsvd_[type]_[fieldname], although some types are not scoped to a field

```
ct = count
gc = group count (the count for a stats "grouping", not scoped to a field)
nc = numerical count (number of numerical values)
sm = sum
ss = sum of squares
v = version (not scoped to a field)
vt = value type (contains the precision of this field)
```

So for example, the count for a field named 'foobar' is stored as psrsvd_ct_foobar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated list, which is now highlighted in Splunk [docs](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.1/Knowledge/UseSireportingcommands):

- ct = count
- gc = group count (the count for a stats "grouping," not scoped to a single field.
- nc = numerical count (number of numerical values)
- nn = minimum numerical value
- nx = maximum numerical value
- rd = rdigest of values (values a the number of times they appear)
- sm = sum
- sn = minimum lexicographical value
- ss = sum of squares
- sx = maximum lexicographical value
- v = version (not scoped to a single field)
- vm = value map (all distinct values for the field and the number of times they appear)
- vt = value type (contains the precision of the associated field)